# WebSocketClient socket closes after the android device is kept idle for some time

Tags: android

I am working on an android application which has a client-server architecture. I am creating a WebSocketClient to connect to a server. Every thing works fine till I keep the device idle for sometime. When the device is kept idle for sometime, I connection with the server closes for some reason.

Refer to the following code :

```
        WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient(new URI(path), draft) {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String message) {
        // some code here
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshake) {
        // Some code here
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception ex) {
        // Some code here
        }
    };
    client.connect();
```

I would appreciate if someone would help me as I am not able to resolve this issue since many days.

Comment: You should mention which library you are using. I use https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync which works pretty well. It also closes the connection after some time (TCP timeout, etc) and reconnect it.

Comment: Also, connection are going to close. It's not an ideal connection where you'd stay connected for a long time. Connections break due to a lot of reasons. If it breaks consistently within a shot period of time, I guess that would be an issue.

Comment: Yes... I am using java_websocket.jar library....